# How does a Google Apps account differ from a Google account?

Tags: google-workspace, google-account

There's been some news recently that Google Apps accounts, having previously been not quite as full-featured as regular Google accounts, are being upgraded to included additional services (e.g. Reader) that were only available to regular accounts.

Aside from the change in the service offerings, are there any other noticeable changes?

Edit: more specifically, if I have my own Google Apps account, is there anything on a regular Google account not offered with an Apps account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Apps for your domain is basically the same, but for a custom domain. You buy your domain, point the MX records for your domain to the google servers and you can send and receive email through gmail etc (as an example)

It used to be just gmail, docs, calendar, gtalk and a couple of other apps that you could access through your google apps account, but now they've released a whole lot more.

See http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2010/11/ten-times-more-applications-for-google.html for more details

Answer (score 1):

There are still a few Google products that are not yet available using a Google Apps account, listed [here](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182213).  (Currently: Buzz, Google Storage, Health, Powermeter, and Profiles.)